# How do I convert an array of strings into an array of numbers in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've this array of strings which all are numbers

```
var a = ['11', '15', '16', '17'];
```

Expected output:

```
b = [11, 15, 16, 17];
```

Comment: `b = a.map(Number)`

Comment: `a = ['11', '15', '16', '17'].map(item =>parseInt(item,10)`

Answer (score 4):

```js
var a = ['11', '15', '16', '17'];

var b = a.map(Number);

console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop, and convert each element of the array containing string, into a integer. parseInt() is a method which converts string into a integer, it takes two arguments, first: the string, second: the base number of the integer

```js
var a=["1","2","3"]; 
console.log(a); 
b=[]; 
for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    b[i]=parseInt(a[i],10)
}; 
console.log(b)
```

Comment: It's SImpler and more Logical